# A potential pitfall of the use of dummy-indices in tensor notation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, tensor-calculus

This is a trick question. I know things should not be in this way but I fell into this trap. I couldn't find out what my misunderstanding is. Here it goes.

I know the electromagnetic field strength should be:
$$F^{\mu \nu} = \partial^\mu A^\nu - \partial^\nu A^\mu$$
And if I derive it once:
$$\partial_\mu F^{\mu \nu} = \partial_\mu \partial^\mu A^\nu - \partial_\mu \partial^\nu A^\mu$$
If $\mu$ is the dummy index in both parts of the equation, I think I should be able to change it as $\mu \rightarrow \nu$. But this leads to:
$$\partial_\mu F^{\mu \nu} = \partial_\nu \partial^\nu A^\nu - \partial_\nu \partial^\nu A^\nu = 0$$
We also know that the equations of motion for the electromagnetic field is $\partial_\mu F^{\mu \nu} = j^\nu$. So what I did clearly eliminates the **four-current**, which is non-sense. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't change a dummy index to be the same thing as a non-dummy index.

Comment: Ok, it's clear now. Thanks.